# Creating JDeveloper remote Database Connections

Tags: oracle11g, jdeveloper

I'm hoping I'll be able to get some help with this. I am new to jdeveloper and Oracle. I installed Oracle 11g database on a remote windows VPS and whenever I try to establish the connection from a different PC I get the error Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.

I am able to connect to the database if installed on localhost. Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the error code you are getting to get better help.
Usually this has to do with settings of SQLNet on the server side, you need to have your Listener running and configured for the right DB.

lsnrctl stat 
should show you the current status (on the server).